# Which exception should I raise for a REST API error?

Tags: python, rest, exception

I am writing a simple API client in Python and I am wondering what exception should I raise if the remote server is not happy.

The API itself is very poorly documented (I don't know all the possible error messages so I can't just define custom classes for all of them), I am letting Requests handle HTTP-level errors which raises `HTTPError` in those cases, but what should I raise if the server just supplies an `error` key in the JSON response?

I am currently using `Exception` but that feels quite broad, I'd like to know whether there's a better alternative.

Regards.

Comment: You have actually answered your question. I don't know all the possible error messages so I can't just define custom classes for all of them. If you know what exact error the server has returned and if you know whether the users of your client might want to handle them then start defining Exception classes of your own.

Comment: HTTP is not a very strict protocol, and several implementations differ *a lot* in terms of how they handle different return codes (e.g. everyone will know what to do with 404, but 416 is practically unheard off in implementations although it is a completely valid return code).  Whatever you do you need to be careful to document your implementation carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just raising `Exception` is likely too broad.

Usually a module should define his own base exception class:

```
class MyAPIClientError(Exception):
    pass
```

And then you can subclass that:

```
class RemoteServerNotHappyError(MyAPIClientError):
    pass
```

`RemoteServerNotHappyError` should probably mention something about what the server's json returned that was not expected by your API client class.  Add in the relevant error messages as you see fit.

This means users of your library can catch these specific exceptions (which they might know how to handle), without having to catch every exception (they surely don't know how to handle every possible failure mode).